# Reverse for 'update_prices' not found. 'update_prices' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

i am building an amazon web scraper where you can submit a link and track the price of your product.

When i try to go to this site this error pops up and it also says that the error is at line 0 at base.html

How do i get rid of this error

**models.py**

````
    from django.db import models
    from .utils import get_link_data
    # Create your models here.
    
    class Link(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True)
        url = models.URLField()
        current_price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
        old_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
        price_difference = models.FloatField(default=0)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('price_difference', '-created')
    
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            name, price = get_link_data(self.url)
            old_price = self.current_price
            if self.current_price:
                if price != old_price:
                    diff = price - old_price
                    self.price_difference = round(diff, 2)
                    self.old_price = old_price
            else:
                self.old_price = 0
                self.price_difference = 0
    
            self.name = name
            self.current_price = price
    
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)```
    
    **views.py**
    
    ```from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy
    from .models import Link
    from .forms import AddLinkForm
    from django.views.generic import DeleteView
    
    def home_view(request):
        no_discounted = 0
        error = None
    
        form = AddLinkForm(request.POST or None)
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            try:
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
            except AttributeError:
                error = "Ups ... couldn't get the name or the price"
            except:
                error = "Ups ... something went wrong"
    
        form = AddLinkForm()
    
        qs = Link.objects.all()
        items_no = qs.count()
    
        if items_no > 0:
            discount_list = []
            for item in qs:
                if item.old_price > item.current_price:
                    discount_list.append(item)
                no_discounted = len(discount_list)
    
        context = {
            'qs': qs,
            'items_no': items_no,
            'no_discounted': no_discounted,
            'form': form,
            'error': error,
        }
    
        return render(request, 'links/main.html', context)
    
    class LinkDeleteView(DeleteView):
        model = Link
        template_name = 'links/confirm_del.html'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    
    def update_prices(request):
        qs = Link.objects.all()
        for link in qs:
            link.save()
        return redirect('home')
````

base.html

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <title>My amazon price tracker</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container mt-3">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}
        </div>
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**main.html**

````
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {% block content %}
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="addItemModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add an Item for Tracking</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{form|crispy}}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Save</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-left">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addItemModal">Add</button>
                <a href="{% url 'update_prices' %}">
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col" style="text-align:right">
                <div>Total Number of Items Being Tracked: {{items_no}}</div>
                <div>Total Number of Discounted Items: {{no_discounted}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if qs %}
            {% for item in qs %}
                <div class="card mt-3">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5>{{item.name}}</h5>
                        <a href="{% url 'delete' item.pk %}"><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="blockquote">
                            <div>Current Price ($): {{item.current_price}}</div>
                            <div>Original Price ($): {{item.old_price}}</div>
                            <div>Difference ($): {{item.price_difference}}</div>
                            <div>Link: <a href="{{item.url}}" target="_blank">{{item.url}}</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <h3> No Items Being Tracked</h3>
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock content %

}```

**confirm_del.html**
````

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content%}
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are You Sure You Want To Delete The Link: "{{object.name}}"</p>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button></a>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock content%}
```

````
**urls.py**

    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from links.views import home_view, update_prices, LinkDeleteView
    
    ```urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', home_view, name='home'),
        path('update/', update_prices, name='update-prices'),
        path('delete/<pk>/', LinkDeleteView.as_view(), name="delete"),
    ]```
    
    **utils.py**
    
    ```import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import lxml
    
    def get_link_data(url):
        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept-Language": "en"
        }
    
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    
        name = soup.select_one(selector="#productTitle").getText()
        name = name.strip()
    
        price = soup.select_one(selector="#priceblock_ourprice").getText()
        price = float(price[1:])
    
        return name, price
````

**settings.py**

```
    from pathlib import Path
    
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    
    DEBUG = True
    
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
    
    
    # Application definition
    
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
        'links',
    
        'crispy_forms',
    ]
    
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]
    
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'amazon_web_scraper.urls'
    
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
    
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'amazon_web_scraper.wsgi.application'
    
    
    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases
    
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }
    
    
    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
    
    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]
    
    
    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/
    
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
    
    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
    
    USE_I18N = True
    
    USE_L10N = True
    
    USE_TZ = True
    
    
    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
    
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    
    # crispy forms
    CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

**forms.py**

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import Link
    
    class AddLinkForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Link
            fields = ('url', )
```

the error also says that is is from base.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name in your `urls.py` file is `update-prices` while you're referencing it as `update_prices`. It's a mismatch due to - vs _.